# Auto Increment Push Notification Badge in Cordova App (Hybrid App)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to Auto Increment Push Notification Badge in Cordova App (Hybrid App).
I am using Ionic framework to develop the app.

When I get push notification from server. I want to auto update Badge Count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rootScope.$apply();
 is needed to reflect your changes. Used rootScope variable to reflect notification count.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    FCMPlugin.getToken(function(token) {
        console.log('Device Token : ' + token);
        DataSharingService.setItem('deviceToken', token);
    });

    //FCMPlugin.onNotification( onNotificationCallback(data), successCallback(msg), errorCallback(err) )
    //Here you define your application behaviour based on the notification data.
    FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data) {

        console.log('Recived data : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        **$rootScope.notificationCountValue = $rootScope.notificationCountValue + 1;**
        $rootScope.notificationArray.push(data);
        DataSharingService.setItem('notificationData', $rootScope.notificationArray);
        **$rootScope.$apply();**

        if (data.wasTapped) {
            //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            App.go('notifications', { obj: data });

        } else {
            //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });


  });
```